# RIA liblaries/framework in day-to-day development

Tags: javascript, web-applications, gwt, ria

I need to develop quite simple web application with some Ajax functionality and GUI components with Java as a server-side language. The main purpose for me is to learn sth about designing web app that I can make use of when I start looking for a job ... .I ran into lots of framework ([RAP](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/),  [Nice JSF implementations](http://www.primefaces.org/) etc.) and there are also [GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/webtoolkit/) and [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) . I started reading about GWT and it seems to be great at the beginning, but there are limited number of visual components. When You missed one it seems to be much harder to write it with GWT than in JavaScript/JQuery (e.g [sortable components](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)).
Also:

- If JavaScript is is easy why to learn API to just make translation?
  The main argument seems to be that GWT is for developers who don't
  know Java Script very well, but is JS harder than GWT API and
  configuration to work with?
- GWT offers also very nice Remote Procedure Call and translating
  objects to JS, but there are lots of libraries like [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html).
- You need also to use standard servlet to e.g send file stream to a
  user, so You need also to save it to a Database or as a hidden XHTML files to make them available to servlet.

So should I start to learn GWT? It is really wide spread? Or maybe JSF implementations with Ajax support outperforms GWT in usability? The biggest problem I have that I cannot imagine how to solve simple problems in GWT while they are almost complete solutions with JQuery. Mixing JavaScript native code with GWT don't seems to be a good option also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with GWT, its always better to now whats going on behind. So you have to learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript as anyway. Maybe you can start with less knowledge on browser frontend technologies. But you will come to the point where you need to know whats going on.

So ask yourself. Is your app large enough that its worth to start with complex GWT app. Also if you're on a large team and familiar with JAVA, Maven and Junit it makes senses.

On the other hand there are a bunch of small ([backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) with jquery), middle ([mootools](http://mootools.net/)) or large ([extjs](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)) JavaScript frameworks to build RIA.

I've never work with JSF, but all people a meet that used it, wasn't really satisfied.

After all I dont think its a good idea to select a framework by the current feature set of your app. As this can change of the time, you will have to implement it later with a technologie you not familiar with.

Note there is a table sort library for GWT as well: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-advanced-table/

Comment: Knowledge of CSS + HTML + JavaScript is not a problem. I wanted to let a user to set items in order. GWT don't even provide drag and drop out of the box (only for HTML5 browsers). There is a plugin for this, but in general there aren't any up to date projects for this kind of components.

Comment: There is a lib for this: http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html#FlowPanelExample. We using it on a large project and works well. But you're right GWT has a lack of support for features that other frameworks offer natively or by plugins for especially latest html5 feature.

Answer (score 1):

GWT contains several unique features which make it difficult to be compared with other frameworks. The key point is that GWT isn't just a framework or library -- it's a toolkit. Consider:

1. Ability to use Java IDE's and debugger during development
2. Automatic generation of compiled scripts optimized for different browsers
3. Benefits of java for organization of code-base: OOP, package system, checked exceptions, compile-time type-checking etc.

These features make GWT suitable for big projects built by large teams that should be enhanced and maintained over a large time-frame. Off course, many projects do not have such requirements and therefore developers should give more weight to other consideration like widget library and learning curve.